# What's a good way to store project related pictures?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to get an array of `PictureBox` to display a list of pictures (in png file format).

I tried to use the .NET `ImageList` control but it insists in re-sizing my pictures. It also does not support transparent background of those png files.

I also tried to use the `Assembly` to retrieve my files like this:
`_imageStream = _assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("MyNamespace.MyImage.png");`
but the code does not return me any resource files nor does it throw any run-time error.

My question is, is there any other ways to do this? Or better yet, can I somehow make the `ImageList` control to NOT alter my picture? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this although I am not sure that this is the best one or not:-

```
 Assembly ambly = Assembly.LoadFile(pathToDll);
```

or

```
 BitMap bitMap;
 // where "ns" is the default namespace of the resource project    
 using (Stream resourceStream = ambly.GetManifestResourceSream("ns.image.jpg"))
 {
  bitMap = BitMap.FromStream(resourceStream);
 }
```

An example:-

```
 interface IThemeResourceProvider
 {
 Stream LoadBigLogo();
 Stream LoadSmallLogo();
 }
```

Then implement that interface in your resource library

```
 public class ThemeResourceProvider : IThemeResourceProvider
 {
 public Stream LoadBigLogo()
 {
     Assembly ambly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
     return ambly.GetManifestResourceStream("namespace.image.jpg");
  }

  (...)
  }
```

Finally, instead of loading the resource directly in your main application, you instantiate the IThemeResourceProvider found in the resource library

```
    Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(pathToDll);

   var results = from type in assembly.GetTypes()
           where typeof(IThemeResourceProvider).IsAssignableFrom(type)
           select type;
```

Now you have an IEnumerable in that list. Typically, you'd only have one, but using this approach you could also host multiple sets of resources, and implement multiple IThemeResourceProviders in the same resource dll. You could e.g. identify each IThemeResourceProvider with a name, either as a property, or using a custom [Attribute] decoration on your various implementations. I'll leave the rest up to you to figure out.

But here's how to instantiate the IThemeResourceProviders in your list

```
    foreach (var providerType in results)
   {
  var constructorInfo = providerType.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
  IThemeResourceProvider provider = constructorInfo.Invoke(null);
   }
```

And finally, using one of these providers to get a bitmap:

```
  BitMap bitMap;
  using (Stream resourceStream = provider.LoadBigLogo())
  {
   bitMap = BitMap.FromStream(resourceStream);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that I got from someone and it's worked well for me!

```
    private void SetImage(PictureBox pb) {
        try {
            Image img = pb.Image;

            Size imgSize = GenerateImageDimensions( img.Width, img.Height, pb.Width, pb.Height );
            Bitmap finalImg = new Bitmap( img, imgSize.Width, imgSize.Height );
            Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage( img );
            gfx.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

            pb.Image = null;
            pb.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize;
            pb.Image = finalImg;
        } catch(Exception ex) {

        }
    }
    public Size GenerateImageDimensions(int currW, int currH, int destW, int destH) {
        //double to hold the final multiplier to use when scaling the image
        double multiplier = 0;

        //string for holding layout
        string layout;

        //determine if it's Portrait or Landscape
        if(currH > currW) layout = "portrait";
        else layout = "landscape";

        switch(layout.ToLower()) {
            case "portrait":
                //calculate multiplier on heights
                if(destH > destW) {
                    multiplier = (double) destW / (double) currW;
                } else {
                    multiplier = (double) destH / (double) currH;
                }
                break;
            case "landscape":
                //calculate multiplier on widths
                if(destH > destW) {
                    multiplier = (double) destW / (double) currW;
                } else {
                    multiplier = (double) destH / (double) currH;
                }
                break;
        }

        //return the new image dimensions
        return new Size( (int) (currW * multiplier), (int) (currH * multiplier) );
    }
```

EDIT: Full disclosure all my images are jpg so I have no clue how this will hand transparent backgrounds.

EDIT TWO:  Also you will need to adjust the `pb.SizeMode` to fit your needs.  The way I did it was to set a max size for the `PictureBox` and it's worked well.